# Is there any limitation in friend function to alloc memory to array member?

Tags: c++, c++17

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas:

I found a reproductive [*error*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAaOa.png) in **template class** when I tried to **alloc more space** for a dynamic array member managed by a pointer with a **friend function**. If I turn to another member function, or just in the Push(), to finish this process, error vanished.

- Independent from private/public accessibility, Error cover all field of array member **accession**, once I tried to **read** or **delete** element in it, error happend.
- No clear tips were given by GCC compiler. Error didn't affect basic types, like int.
- Binding friend & Unbinding friend **both** suffer from this error

  Is there anything wrong in my code, or there is some limitation I didn't know in using memory function?

  Every opinion, link and anwser is appreciated.

  PS: To make posted code more clearly, I **simplify** some unimportant code. But to provide **enough imformation**, it still looks **so long**, feel sorry to the 
  reading difficulty.

  PS2:Guarantee can be made that code simplified is **correct.**

Error occurs both in **Debug** mode(x64 and x86),Visual Studio 2017 
and **cmake** 3.13.4-**GCC** 7.2.0 toolchain debugging with gdb in VScode.

```
//Bizcard.hpp
class Bizcard
{
private:
 char *name;
  char *phone;
public:
  Bizcard();
  Bizcard(const char* n,const char* phone);//constructor
  Bizcard(const Bizcard &b);//copy constructor
  Bizcard& operator=(const Bizcard& b);//assignment operator
  ~Bizcard();
};
```

```
//Bizcard.cpp
#include"Bizcard.hpp"
#include<string.h>
#include<iostream>
Bizcard::Bizcard()
{
    name = nullptr;
    phone = nullptr;
}
Bizcard::Bizcard(const char* n ,const char* p)
{
    //simplified...
}

Bizcard::Bizcard(const Bizcard &b)
{
    //simplified...
}

Bizcard& Bizcard::operator=(const Bizcard& b)
{
    if(this==&b)
        return *this;

    delete[] this->name;//Error would occur here if using 
                        //friend func to expand array capacity
    delete[] this->phone;

    if(b.name==nullptr)
        {
            name = nullptr;
            phone = nullptr;
            return *this;
        }
    int nlen = strlen(b.name);
    int plen = strlen(b.phone);

    this->name = new char[nlen+1];
    strcpy_s(name, nlen + 1, b.name);
    this->phone = new char[plen+1];
    strcpy_s(phone, plen + 1, b.phone);
    return *this;
}

Bizcard::~Bizcard()
{
    delete[] name;
    delete[] phone;
}
```

```
//BagTemplate.hpp
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>
#include"Bizcard.hpp"
template<typename Type>
void ChangeSize1D_binding(Type* array, int old_capacity, int new_capacity)
{
    if(new_capacity<old_capacity)
        throw "Paragram Error! New capacity must greater than the old one.";
    Type* temp_array =new Type[new_capacity];
    std::copy(array,array+old_capacity,temp_array);
    delete[] array;
    array = temp_array;//Point array to the dest of temp_array
}
template<typename T>
class Bag
{
public:
    Bag(int bagCapability =3);
    ~Bag();
   void Push(const T&);
   void ChangeSize1D_self(int old_capacity, int new_capacity);
private:
    T *array;
    int capacity;
    int top;
    friend void ChangeSize1D_binding<T>(T* array, int old_capacity, int new_capacity);
    template<typename Type>
    friend void ChangeSize1D_unbind(Type* array, int old_capacity, int new_capacity);
};

template<typename T>
Bag<T>::Bag(int bagCapacity):capacity(bagCapacity)
{
    if(capacity<1) throw "Capacity must be >0";
    array = new T[capacity];
    top = -1;
}

template<typename T>
Bag<T>::~Bag()
{
    delete[] array;
}
template<typename T>
void Bag<T>::ChangeSize1D_self(int old_capacity,int new_capacity)
{
    if(new_capacity<old_capacity)
        throw "Paragram Error! New capacity must greater than the old one.";
    T* temp_array =new T[new_capacity];
    std::copy(array,array+old_capacity,temp_array);
    delete[] array;
    array = temp_array;
}

template<typename Type>
void ChangeSize1D_unbind(Type* array, int old_capacity, int new_capacity)
{
    if(new_capacity<old_capacity)
        throw "Paragram Error! New capacity must greater than the old one.";
    Type* temp_array =new Type[new_capacity];
    std::copy(array,array+old_capacity,temp_array);
    delete[] array;
    array = temp_array;
}

template<typename T>
void Bag<T>::Push(const T& x)
{
    if(capacity ==top+1)
    {   
        //this->ChangeSize1D_self(capacity,2*capacity);
        ChangeSize1D_unbind(array,capacity, 2*capacity);
        //ChangeSize1D_binding(array,capacity, 2*capacity);
        /*T* temp_array = new T[2 * capacity];
        std::copy(array,array+capacity,temp_array);
        delete[] array;
        array = temp_array;*/
        capacity*=2;
    }
    array[++top]=x;
}
```

```
//main.cpp
int main()
{
     Bag<int> IntBag;
    IntBag.Push(1);
    IntBag.Push(1);
    IntBag.Push(1);
    IntBag.Push(1);
    Bag<Bizcard> BizcardBag;
    BizcardBag.Push(Bizcard());
    BizcardBag.Push(Bizcard());
    BizcardBag.Push(Bizcard());
    BizcardBag.Push(Bizcard());//Error may happen here since Push() it need        
                              //expanding capacity(origin value: 3)
    /*1.as predict, Push success if change size process is directly in Push()
        2.when turn to ChangeSize1D(), same error occur
            2.1 when change to private member func, no error
            2.2 when change to public member func, no error
            2.3 when change to private unbinding friend func, same error occur;means private or public doesnt effect behaviour
            2.4 when change to private binding friend func, same error occur
    */
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

```
#CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(BugReproduct)

include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Bizcard")
add_subdirectory("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Bizcard")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED true)

add_executable(BugReproduct ArrayExpansion.cpp)
target_link_libraries(BugReproduct Bizcard)
```

```
#Bizcard/CMakeList.txt
add_library(Bizcard Bizcard.cpp)
```

Comment: Please don't mess with memory allocation yourself. You don't need to do that in modern c++ code.

Comment: I do know about it. But I think it is a good chance to know deeper on how cpp works. When I work on my project, I prefer STL library best, "Don't reinvent the wheel", Right?

Comment: If you want to have strings, use `std::string`. And  if you want to learn arrays, pointers and dynamic allocation, then please do some exercises about that only. Don't try to make it part of a bigger project, where it can get lost among so much other things.

Comment: Thanks for advise and I did. Never using such self-defined, crude container in my project. These error is found in an exercise I have did, and I just wonder why this error happend, since in knowledge from book or experience from project development, friend function seems can do everything to member variant like menber function can. Do you have any idea about this? Hoping for an anwser.

Comment: What happens in the copy constructor for Bizcard::Bizcard(const Bizcard& b)?  Depending on what the compiler chooses to do it may be that in some cases it winds up effectively using the copy constructor instead.

Comment: Thanks for advise. Since copy constructor seems not important here, I simplified it. But I can make sure that its code is mostly same as operator=(). I  wonder what happen when Bag class expand its capacity by using friend func (ChangSize1D_unbind or ChangSize1D_binding). Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: Problem SOLVED, this error happened because I pass the pointer directly to friend func, thus friend func would hold a copy but not reference or pointer to it. When I changed the destination the copied "array"  pointed to in friend func, which changed the address value it saved, such process do nothing to the real array pointer outside, leading to error when I access the extra alloc element. Profound appreciate to all the help you ever gave. Thank you all.

Comment: If you've found the solution to your problem, you can post it as an answer rather than leave it in a comment.

Comment: Thank you! I messed up "Ask your question" and "Answer your question" before, thus couldnot find the post button below. XD

Answer (score 0):

Problem SOLVED, this error happened because I pass the pointer directly to friend func, thus friend func would hold a copy but not reference or pointer to it. When I changed the destination the copied "array" pointed to in friend func, which changed the address value it saved, such process do nothing to the real array pointer outside, leading to error when I access the extra alloc element.

This issue can be another footnote about how dangerous pointer is and how much effort should be made before using pointer prefectly.

Profound appreciate to all the help you ever gave. Thank you all.